# Python: user input in condition does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code. Here `if` condition does not work only show `else` message. Help please.

```
var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
if(var==10):print"equal"
else:print "not qual"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a *string*, but you are comparing that string to an integer. Python won't automatically convert between the types.

Either compare to a string:

```
if var == '10':
```

or convert `var` to an integer:

```
var = int(var)
```

The latter will raise a `ValueError` exception if `var` is not convertable to an integer, and you may want to handle that case. Also see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` in Python2.x will return as string , you have to use `int()`
to switch type:

```
var  = raw_input("number:")
try:
  num_var = int(var)
except ValueError:
  print "value error"

if num_var == 10:
  print 'ten'
```

Or you can use `input()` to get input a number:

```
>>> num = input()
100
>>> num + 1
101
```

If you want to use `input()` to get a string, you have to add something in the string :

```
>>> string_x = input()
'ok'
>>> string_x
'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

just use input() instead of raw_input() which will automatically evaluate the user input. 
Hope that helps! :)